# app service stopped working after enable application insights extension on portal

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

Have an webapi deployed on Azure App Service, after enable the application insights extension on portal, the webapi shows 'cannot find resources'. Did some google, added application insights to the visual studio project, redeployed, now getting the error below,

> ' Could not load file or assembly
>   'ProductionBreakpointsHostingObserver, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d3bb6c79cff225a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. '

not sure what is issue now, help please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the application insights extension? or create a new Webapp and try it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same error and I think it was related to an upgrade of Application Insights libraries.

I solved it by removing the references to old Application Insights packages in the project file and *packages.config* file (those with *Microsoft.AI* namespace).

After **publish** the application again and **restarting** it on Azure portal the error disappeared.